# Como configurar o terminal do doctrine juntamente com um projecto Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine

Estou a fazer a integração do Doctrine no Codeigniter mas estou com problemas na configuração da linha de commandos.

Em primeiro lugar importa mencionar que segui o guia [disponibilizado na página do Doctrine.](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html)

Para fazer a instalação das dependencias corretamente usei o Composer. 
Desse modo a estrutura do projecto encontra-se organizada do seguinte modo:

```
/application
--Libraries   <---- Doctrine.php encontra-se aqui
/vendor       <---- aqui encontram-se as libs instaladas para o doctrine
/system
index.php     <---- essas libs são carregadas no root do projecto
...
```

No ficheiro de configurações do codeigniter adicionei a Lib "Doctrine" em autoload.
Até aqui tudo bem! Se arrancar a aplicação no browser funciona direitinho.

O problema está na hora de configurar a linha de comandos do doctrine que entre muitas funcionalidades permite gerar os "models" de forma automatizada a partir da base de dados.

Segundo o tutorial basta criar um ficheiro .php chamado cli-config.php

Pelo que consegui apurar esse ficheiro deve ser colocado num destes directorios.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(52) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Project/main/app"
  [1]=>
  string(59) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Project/main/app/config"
}
```

Se eu navegar através do "explorer do windows" ou do finder do mac até à pasta vendor/bin e abrir o ficheiro de linha de comandos de nome doctrine um erro surge dizendo:

```
You are missing a "cli-config.php" or "config/cli-config.php" file in your
project, which is required to get the Doctrine Console working. You can use the
following sample as a template:

<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

// replace with file to your own project bootstrap
require_once 'bootstrap.php';

// replace with mechanism to retrieve EntityManager in your app
$entityManager = GetEntityManager();

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

Logo aqui tenho uma dúvida! O que é que eles querem dizer com:

```
// replace with file to your own project bootstrap
require_once 'bootstrap.php';
```

Assumindo que aqui devo referenciar o index.php (ficheiro central do meu projeto codeigniter) eu criei um ficheiro no root do projecto chamado cli-config.php tal como deve ser feito (de acordo com a mensagem de erro).

Tudo OK. Fui na linha de comando e naveguei até ao root do meu projecto codeigniter
Usando os métodos do composer (PHP) digitei.

> php vendor/bin/doctrine
>   o resultado do output de uma mensagem de erro.

```
...
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
        <p>Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.</p><p>Filename: core/Loader.php</p><p>Line Number: 346</p>    </div>
</body>
```

Alguém me consegue ajudar? Eu acho que percebi errado aquilo que eles pretendem com "replace with file to your own project bootstrap" no tutorial.

Comment: vc configurou alguma variavel de ambiente?

Comment: não, mas acho que não deve ser necessário pois o commando php foi instalado pelo composer e está disponível.  Se eu fizer php -help consigo visualizar a lista de opcões disponiveis

Comment: Vc esta tentando configura no mac ou windows?

Comment: Eu estou usando MAC

Answer (score 1):

Pelo visto o Doctrine não está conseguindo reconhecer e configurar automaticamente a estrutura e hierarquia dos diretórios da sua aplicação, tente re-fazer a instalação das dependências do Doctrine dentro de uma mesma pasta, exemplo:

```
application/
libraries/
    doctrine/
        {Doctrine Lib}
        composer.json
```

Ficando com a seguinte estrutura:

```
application/
libraries/
    doctrine/
        Doctrine/
            … some libs of Doctrine library
        vendor/
            … some dependencies libraries
```

Pelo fato de o CodeIgniter não seguir os padrões sugeridos pela PHP-FIG fica meio chato implementar algumas bibliotecas no mesmo, por isso dou preferência a Frameworks que já seguem este padrão como Symfony2, Zend Framework 2, Laravel e etc.

Answer (score 0):

Respondi agora pouco uma pergunta sobre como [integrar o Doctrine com o CodeIgniter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63710/4751).

Criei o arquivo `cli-config.php` copiando alguns trechos do `index.php` e referenciando o 
`EntityManager` criado no `libraries\Doctrine.php`.

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

// Constantes do CodeIgniter
define('APPPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/application/');
define('BASEPATH', APPPATH . '/../system/');
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');

// Inclusão da classe do Doctrine
chdir(APPPATH);
require APPPATH . '/libraries/Doctrine.php';

$doctrine = new Doctrine();
$entityManager = $doctrine->em;

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

Para referencia, veja como ficou meu [`libraries\Doctrine.php`](https://github.com/gmsantosxl/ci3-doctrine/blob/master/application/libraries/Doctrine.php).