# Instalar o Codeigniter 3 com Doctrine e Composer

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine, composer

Qual a melhor maneira de instalar o [doctrine](/questions/tagged/doctrine) via [composer](/questions/tagged/composer) no [codeigniter](/questions/tagged/codeigniter) 3.0? Pretendo deixar os arquivos na pasta `libraries`.

Criei o arquivo `composer.json`:

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "application/libraries"
    },
    "require": {
        "doctrine/common": "2.4.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.4.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*" 
    }
}
```

Executei o comando **`php composer.phar install`**, criando os arquivos dentro da pasta `application/libraries` no Codeigniter 3.0.

Criei um library chamada `Doctrine.php` e adicionei no `autoload`:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('doctrine');
```

O `doctrine.php`:

```
<?php
//AutoLoader do Composer
$loader = require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
//vamos adicionar nossas classes ao AutoLoader
$loader->add('Pasta_library', __DIR__);


use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

//se for falso usa o APC como cache, se for true usa cache em arrays
$isDevMode = false;

//caminho das entidades
$paths = array(__DIR__ );
// configurações do banco de dados
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'   => 'dnp',
);

$config = Setup::createConfiguration($isDevMode);

//leitor das annotations das entidades
$driver = new AnnotationDriver(new AnnotationReader(), $paths);
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
//registra as annotations do Doctrine
AnnotationRegistry::registerFile(
    __DIR__ . '/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php'
);
//cria o entityManager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

Ao tentar subir o projeto, aparecem as mensagens de erro:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/Users/israel/Sites/agemed/application/libraries/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in
>   /Users/israel/Sites/agemed/application/libraries/Doctrine.php on line
>   3

Mostrando que o sistema não está localizando o caminho correto.

Onde corrigir?

Comment: o Doctrine.php esta em qual pasta do projeto ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Subi no [GitHub um projeto exemplo](https://github.com/gmsantos/ci3-doctrine) integrando o CodeIgniter 3 com o Doctrine, acompanhado de um exemplo.

---

O erro está na maneira que você utiliza o *autoloading*.

No arquivo `doctrine.php` o correto na linha 3 seria:

```
$loader = require APPPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

---

Porém incluir na unha o *autoload*  dentro do `Doctrine.php` é desnecessário no Codeigniter 3. Ele possui uma configuração que já injeta o *autoload* do Composer na nossa aplicação.

Configure o arquivo `config.php`

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

Ou se preferir utilizar a pasta `vendor` na raiz do projeto (meu caso), insira o caminho para o `autoload.php`.

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Utilizando a segunda opção podemos tirar do nosso `composer.json` a config `"vendor-dir" : "application/libraries"`.

---

Meu arquivo `libraries\Doctrine.php` é um pouco diferente também. Utilizei um arquivo baseado [nessa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17125896/2099835).

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader,
    Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup,
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class Doctrine
{
    public $em;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Load the database configuration from CodeIgniter
        require APPPATH . 'config/database.php';

        $connection_options = array(
            'driver'        => 'pdo_mysql',
            'user'          => $db['default']['username'],
            'password'      => $db['default']['password'],
            'host'          => $db['default']['hostname'],
            'dbname'        => $db['default']['database'],
            'charset'       => $db['default']['char_set'],
            'driverOptions' => array(
                'charset'   => $db['default']['char_set'],
            ),
        );

        // With this configuration, your model files need to be in application/models/Entity
        // e.g. Creating a new Entity\User loads the class from application/models/Entity/User.php
        $models_namespace = 'Entity';
        $models_path = APPPATH . 'models';
        $proxies_dir = APPPATH . 'models/Proxies';
        $metadata_paths = array(APPPATH . 'models');

        // Set $dev_mode to TRUE to disable caching while you develop
        $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($metadata_paths, $dev_mode = true, $proxies_dir);
        $this->em = EntityManager::create($connection_options, $config);

        $loader = new ClassLoader($models_namespace, $models_path);
        $loader->register();
    }
}
```

Para utilizar o *Doctrine*, crie uma pasta `Entity` dentro de `models` e insira ali dentro suas *Entities* dentro do namespace `Entity`

```
<?php namespace Entity;

/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="products")
 **/
class Product
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;
    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    protected $name;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Após incluir o `Doctrine.php` no *autoload* do Codeigniter (`$autoload['libraries'] = array('doctrine');`) posso utilizar a *Entity* no meu *controller*.

```
public function index()
{
    $product = new Entity\Product();

    $product->setName('Teste');

    $this->doctrine->em->persist($product);
    $this->doctrine->em->flush();       
}
```

Comment: Israel, conseguiu entender a ideia?